# Sorting lines of a text file using a GUI (java)

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, user-interface, comparator

I have a text file with 20 hockey players and their stats. Using buttons in a GUI, I want to sort players from greatest to least in a chosen stat. When I click a button, my file does not change.

I'm thinking there is a problem with my variable SortCol, but I can't figure out what's wrong.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { //method for what will happen when the Enter button is clicked
            Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in); //creates scanner named console
            Object[][] statArray = new Object[20][]; //created 2-Dimensional Object array named statArray so I can store different data types from my file
            for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) { //created a loop that will run 20 times
                statArray[i] = new Object[8];
            }

            int lines = 0; //set variable named lines to hold a value of 0

            while (in.hasNextLine()) { //while loop that repeats until every line has been read
                String line = in.nextLine(); //creates a String Variable named line for each line
                Scanner readLine = new Scanner(line); //created Scanner named readLine

                while (readLine.hasNext()) { //created another while loop that repeats until a each token in a line has been read
                    statArray[lines][0] = readLine.next();//in these next 9 lines, I placed each token into my array, using my scanner
                    statArray[lines][1] = readLine.next();
                    statArray[lines][2] = readLine.nextDouble();
                    statArray[lines][3] = readLine.nextDouble();
                    statArray[lines][4] = readLine.nextDouble();
                    statArray[lines][5] = readLine.nextDouble();
                    statArray[lines][6] = readLine.nextDouble();
                    statArray[lines][7] = readLine.nextDouble();
                    lines++;
                }
                readLine.close(); //closes my readLine Scanner
            }

                if (e.getSource() == sortGames) {
                    sortCol = 2;

                } else if (e.getSource() == sortGoals) {
                    sortCol = 3;

                } else if (e.getSource() == sortAssists) {
                    sortCol = 4;

                } else if (e.getSource() == sortPoints) {
                    sortCol = 5;

                } else if (e.getSource() == sortShots) {
                    sortCol = 6;

                } else if (e.getSource() == sortShotPercentage) {
                    sortCol = 7;

                }
                final Comparator<Object[]> arrayComparator = new Comparator<Object[]>() { //compares a column in my array
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Object[] array1, Object[] array2) {
                        return (((Double) array2[sortCol]).compareTo((Double) array1[sortCol])); //returns the sorted array
                    }
                };

                Arrays.sort(statArray, arrayComparator);

                outputFile.printf("%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s", "Player", "Name", "GP", "G", "A", "P", "S", "S%\n");//prints the header


                for (int rows = 0; rows < statArray.length; rows++) { //for loop used to print each row

                    outputFile.printf("\n%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s%-10s", statArray[rows][0], statArray[rows][1], statArray[rows][2], statArray[rows][3], statArray[rows][4], statArray[rows][5], statArray[rows][6], statArray[rows][7]);//prints the sorted stats in the file, nicely formatted
                    console.close(); //closes my console Scanner
                    in.close(); //closes my in Scanner
                }
```

Comment: I would recommend you create a class `HockeyPlayer` with all stats as attributes and then you put them in a `List<HockeyPlayer>` (or array) and sort that list. The way you are doing things is not very type safe and hard to follow (-> hard to maintain). For sorting you could then use something like this `Arrays.sort(hockeyPlayerArray, Comparator.comparing(HockeyPlayer::getPoints));`.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest creating an object to represent your player.  Since you're using a GUI, I would then recommend creating your own `TableModel` by extending `AbstractTableModel` and then using that to build a JTable. You can then sort by any field. It should look something like this:

```
public class HockeyPlayer {
    private String name;
    private String team;
    private int games;
    private int goals;
    private int assists;
    private int points;
    private int shots;
    private float shotPercentage;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getTeam() {
        return team;
    }
    public void setTeam(String team) {
        this.team = team;
    }
    public int getGames() {
        return games;
    }
    public void setGames(int games) {
        this.games = games;
    }
    public int getGoals() {
        return goals;
    }
    public void setGoals(int goals) {
        this.goals = goals;
    }
    public int getAssists() {
        return assists;
    }
    public void setAssists(int assists) {
        this.assists = assists;
    }
    public int getPoints() {
        return points;
    }
    public void setPoints(int points) {
        this.points = points;
    }
    public int getShots() {
        return shots;
    }
    public void setShots(int shots) {
        this.shots = shots;
    }
    public float getShotPercentage() {
        return shotPercentage;
    }
    public void setShotPercentage(float shotPercentage) {
        this.shotPercentage = shotPercentage;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class HockeyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

private List<HockeyPlayer> players = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return 8;
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return players.size();
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
    
    try {
        HockeyPlayer player = players.get(row);
        
        switch (col) {
        case 0:
            return player.getName();
        case 1:
            return player.getTeam();
        case 2:
            return player.getGames();
        case 3:
            return player.getGoals();
        case 4:
            return player.getAssists();
        case 5:
            return player.getPoints();
        case 6:
            return player.getShots();
        case 7:
            return player.getShotPercentage();
        }           
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public String getColumnName(int col) {
    switch (col) {
    case 0:
        return "Name";
    case 1:
        return "Team";
    case 2:
        return "Games";
    case 3:
        return "Goals";
    case 4:
        return "Assists";
    case 5:
        return "Points";
    case 6:
        return "Shots";
    case 7:
        return "Shot Percentage";
    default:
        return "";
    }
}
}
```